# Concatenating string with number in ruby

Tags: ruby

I am total begineer in ruby so its very novice question.

I am trying to concatenate a string with a float value like follows and then printing it.

```
puts " Total Revenue of East Cost: " + total_revenue_of_east_cost
```

total_revenue_of_east_cost is a variable holding float value, how i can make it print?

Answer (score 104, accepted):

This isn't exactly concatenation but it will do the job you want to do:

```
puts " Total Revenue of East Cost: #{total_revenue_of_east_cost}"
```

Technically, this is interpolation. The difference is that concatenation adds to the end of a string, where as interpolation evaluates a bit of code and inserts it into the string. In this case, the insertion comes at the end of your string.

Ruby will evaluate anything between braces in a string where the opening brace is preceded by an octothorpe.

Comment: Thanks, can i know the rule here for concatenation?

Comment: octothorpe is the US speak for hash ;)

Answer (score 57):

Stephen Doyle's answer, using a technique known as "String interpolation" is correct and probably the easiest solution, however there is another way. By calling an objects to_s method that object can be converted to a string for printing. So the following will also work.

```
puts " Total Revenue of East Cost: " + total_revenue_of_east_cost.to_s
```

Comment: BTW: string interpolation calls `to_s` automatically, if the result of the interpolated expression is not a `String` already.

Answer (score 7):

For your example, you might want something more specific than the to_s method.  After all, to_s on a float will often include more or less precision than you wish to display.

In that case,

```
puts " Total Revenue of East Coast: #{sprintf('%.02f', total_revenue_of_east_coast)}"
```

might be better.  #{} can handle any bit of ruby code, so you can use sprintf or any other formatting method you'd like.

Answer (score 5):

I like (see Class String % for details):

```
puts " Total Revenue of East Coast: " + "%.2f" % total_revenue_of_east_coast
```

Comment: how to format when using a Hash: "%002d" % 23 --> 023. "%{k}" % {k: 23} --> 23. How to obtain "023"?.

Comment: So "%002d" % 23 --> 23 not 023. If found "%03d" % 23 --> 023.

Now to use the data from a hash instead of a fixed number, do not alter the format string. 

Just do something like "%03d" % {k: 23}[:k] --> 023

Comment: Stil i'll lose the advantages of using a Hash instead of a list. i.e "Hello {name}, i'm glad your {stuff} is ... So, {name}: What does your {stuff} bla bla bla? ... {stuff} ... {name}" % {:name => "Jesús", :stuff => "pet"}. Imagine that with a list, you have to repeat "name" and "stuff" many times. And now, i want that advantage plus be able to format. How?

Comment: h = {:name => 'bob', :stuff => 23}

sprintf("name = %s, value = %03d", h[:name], h[:stuff])

Comment: Still the same problem. That way, you have to list one by one the values in the order they appear in the template. How to reffer to the values by name from the template and at the same time apply some formating (i.e. numerical formatting %02d).

Answer (score 0):

Example bucle

```
(1..100).each do |i| puts "indice #{i} " end
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).