# print not working in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I created a very simple run calculator for a class assignment, but I can't get it to display on one line.  I want the output to be "Your workout time is X minutes". I can get the first two parts on one line, but when I replace "puts workout_time" with "print workout_time", it doesn't work. I get something that looks like a progress bar, and the message "contacting server". I am using repl.it if that matters. This is my code:

```
#warm up and cool down times are fixed
#user enters remaining values in minutes

warm_up = 4
cool_down = 4
workout_time = []

puts "How many minutes per set do you want to run?" 
run = gets.chomp.to_i

puts "How many minutes do you want to rest each set?"
rest = gets.chomp.to_i 

puts "How many times do you want to repeat the run/walk?"
sets = gets.chomp.to_i

workout_time << (run+rest)*sets + warm_up + cool_down

print "Your workout time will be "  
puts workout_time
puts " minutes"
```

Thanks!

Comment: `puts "Your workout time will be #{workout_time.first} minutes"`. This will do. I don't see why you're using an array anyway, just use an integer.

Comment: Oh wow - thanks! I actually tried that, or I thought I did - I used square brackets instead of curly brackets.

Comment: I agree with @sagarpandya82: There's no need to use an array to hold one value. You can remove the initialization of the `workout_time` variable (or if you keep it use `0` instead of `[]`), and later just assign it: `workout_time = (run+rest)*sets...`

Answer (score 2):

Try to:

```
print "Your workout time will be %d minutes" % [workout_time]
```

Answer (score 1):

See here: [Concatenating string with number in ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1940106/concatenating-string-with-number-in-ruby)

You will want to use a puts statement with "Your workout time is X minutes" but replace the X with #{workout_time} like this:

```
puts "Your workout time will be #{workout_time} minutes"
```