# Why can't I print strings with integers?

Tags: ruby

```
num1 = 2
num2 = 4
op = num1 + num2
puts "enter a number would like to multiply with 6"
num3 = gets.to_i * op
print ("its " + num3 + " man")
```

Why doesnt this work? If i have it as 'print num3' alone itll work. What is going on?

Comment: String's `#+` method can't take an integer argument. Instead you can do `print "its #{num3} man"`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Concatenating string with number in ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1940106/concatenating-string-with-number-in-ruby)

Comment: Well, what does it even *mean* to add a text to a number?

Comment: ` :001 > 'one' + 1 + 'one'` just rises the error without any print or puts.

Answer (score 3):

The answers to this question, [Concatenating string with number in ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1940106/concatenating-string-with-number-in-ruby), outline two ways you can do it via either:

- string interpolation
- or, using .to_s to change the number to a string when constructing the result string

Using .to_s you can do this:

```
print ("its " + num3.to_s + " man")
```

Although using string interpolation may be  a better approach.
Described here:
https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/doc/syntax/literals_rdoc.html

Answer (score 1):

You can't concat Fixnum and string.
Please do it like this.

```rb
print ("its #{num3} man")
```

Answer (score 0):

> If i have it as `print num3` alone it'll work. What is going on?

`print` can indeed print arbitrary objects using their `to_s` methods, even multiple objects.

But in order to do so, you have to pass them as *separate* arguments:

```
num = 42

print('its ', num, ' man')
# its 42 man
```

However, it's more idiomatic to use [string interpolation](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/doc/syntax/literals_rdoc.html#label-Strings):

```
print("its #{num} man")
# its 42 man
```

or [`printf`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Kernel.html#printf-method) which takes a template string: (`%d` means decimal number)

```
printf('its %d man', num)
# its 42 man
```

Note that none of the above will print a newline. If you want one, you have to append `\n` yourself, or use [`puts`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Kernel.html#puts-method) which adds it automatically.